# Fixing the plot region absolutely

Tags: plotting, size

I have seen many posts where people are asking to scale the plot region with another plot, especially for when people are using side-by-side plots.

Is it possible to set the plot region absolutely. For example I may produce some plots in completely separate, and unrelated notebooks but they will be going into something like a thesis.

Is it possible to define the plot region itself in some absolute unit, say in $\rm{mm}$ -- similar to how one can do this in LaTex?

Comment: Does using `ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400`, which sets the plot region to 400 points, accomplish what you need?

Comment: In the documentation of my MaTeX package, there is a section devoted to this: "Preparing Figures to Size". You may find it useful. http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX

Comment: @CarlWoll I'll make a quick test and get  back to you! Thanks for the tip.